# Eslint expected to return a value in function array-callback-return error

Tags: reactjs, function, error-handling, eslint, return-value

In React application trying resolve Eslint issues

```
Object.keys(selected).map(function (key, val) {
          if (selected[key]) {
            selectedItem.push(val)
            selectedItem.push(key)
          }
        });
```

Its a existing code not sure should I change to forEach to solve this Eslint error
tried replacing {}===============> arrow to ()

Please suggest a way to fix this Eslint error

Comment: could you please explain what do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use forEach here. You have to return a value when you use map function.

Please check below URL.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return